# javascript not working on struts html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I have the following codes in a jsp page in my Struts2 project

```
<select id="amountSelect">
 <s:iterator value="rateCardDetailsList" status="listStatusAmount">
    <option value="<s:property value='#listStatusAmount.index'/>"><s:property value="rechargeAmount"/></option>
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

and a corresponding script for this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amountSelect").change(function(){
        var v= $("#amountSelect").val();
        var r= "<s:property value='rateCardDetailsList["+ v +"].mobileRate'/>";
        alert(r);
    });
});
```

where `rateCardDetailsList` is an array of a particular bean(`Object`) which contain the variable `mobileRate`. But I'm getting null at the position of `r` whil alerting (`alert(r);`). On inspecting the element it was as following

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#amountSelect").change(function(){
            var v= $("#amountSelect").val();
            var r= "";
            alert(r);
            
        });
    });
```

Instead of the variable `v` if I direcly give the index I'm getting the value i.e

```
 var r= "<s:property value='rateCardDetailsList[1].mobileRate'/>";
    alert(r);
```

does gives a value in the alert.
What coud be the reason?

Comment: try checking what v is then. and it's  usally better to use console.log instead of alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *wildly* invalid JSP + JavaScript:

```
var r = "<s:property value='rateCardDetailsList["+ v +"].mobileRate'/>";
```

Take a step back and think about where all this code is executing.

JSP, e.g., custom tags (here the `<s:property>` tag) is evaluated on the *server* side, before anything is sent to the browser.

JavaScript is executed on the *client* side, after being rendered on the server and sent to the client. Here you're trying to mix server side code (the tag) with JavaScript code, the string concatenation. Won't even come *close* to working.

To get this to work you need to render valid JavaScript on the *server* side, or use Ajax and get the JS values dynamically, etc. It's common to render JS data structures (e.g., JSON), but there are many other options.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `null` but an empty string `""`.

This is because the `property` tag doesn't return a value.

An exception is thrown and caught inside while parsing the OGNL expression. In this case `property` tag returns nothing.